# Cauchy's Functional Equation

Tags: measure-theory, functional-equations, levy-processes

Consider Cauchy's Functional Equation

$$\phi(t+s)=\phi(t)+\phi(s).$$

Can we say that any right continuous with left limits (cadlag) solution is Borel measurable? Obviously continuous solutions are Borel measureable, however, discontinuous solutions are not. I've also read that measurability can be reduced to cadlag, but I don't see how?

Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

In addition, we can observe that solutions to Cauchy's functional equation are deterministic analogues of Levy processes, however in the definition of Levy processes Cauchy's functional equation is satisfied only up to equality in distribution. Does this enable solutions to become Borel or Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: I don't have an answer (besides @Robert just posted an answer), but hope you might find the following two papers related: http://link.springer.com/article/10.2478%2Fs11533-012-0144-1 also http://dorais.org/files/2012/07/additive.pdf , and also http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm166/fm16634.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. What if Borel measurable is replaced with Lebesgue measurable? Does that change anything?

Comment: You can find more stuff related to measurable solutions of Cauchy's functional equation in the answer to this question: [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](/q/423492).

Comment: I will add that the link in @Mirko's answer which is now dead was most likely link to the preprint of the same paper [doi:s11533-012-0144-1](https://doi.org/10.2478/s11533-012-0144-1). Although, the preprint seems to be no longer available on [Francois G. Dorais' website](http://www.dorais.org/papers/index.html) at the moment it is still available on [Rafal Filipow's website](https://mat.ug.edu.pl/~rfilipow/papers/index.html). The same paper is referenced in [another answer on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411164#411229).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you, the first link (doi) that you give seems to allow for free download and is hopefully "permanent"

Answer (score 2):

Any measurable solution is continuous.  Any nonmeasurable solution is very "wild": in particular its graph is dense in $\mathbb R^2$, so it has no one-sided limits anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you suggesting that any cadlag solution is non measurable?

Comment: No, I'm saying that any cadlag solution is continuous.

Comment: Ok right. Thanks for the clarification. Did you see my edit of the original question?