# Is a set of representatives of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ a Vitali set?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Question**

Let any two real numbers be equivalent if they differ by a dyadic rational.  Is any set of representatives of such a Vitali set?

**My Musings**

I initially thought it was because $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.  Is that sufficient for the proof, or is more needed?

I think the defintion of a Vitali set is that it's a subset of $\Bbb R$ which is not Lebesgue measurable. Informally, I think because $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ that means we can find a set of representatives of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ in any arbitrarily narrow segment of $\Bbb R$ and therefore it's not Lebesgue measureable.

But I'm conscious I'm waving away a lot of *"not really understanding the definition of Lebesque Measurable"* when I write *"and therefore it's not Lebesque measureable"*.

**EDIT**

Ok I found a better definition of a Vitali set which I trust more:

> A Vitali set is a subset $V$ of the interval $[ 0 , 1 ]$ of real numbers such that, for each real number $r$, there is exactly one number $v ∈ V$ such that $v − r$ is a rational number.

I'm currently trying to work out if this makes $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ a Vitali set but it looks doubtful.  Tentatively, I think it gives that it *can* be a Vitali set if chosen appropriately, but it's not necessarily.  Although I think the axiom of choice is still required to define it.  But I'm trying and failing to come up with an example which is not a Vitali set.

...I guess I need a couple of numbers which differ by say $1/3$, right?  And every set of representatives will have a pair differing by $1/3$, correct?  So it can never be a Vitali set.

Comment: Note $\mathbb Z[\frac12]$ is countable, so it is Lebesgue measurable and therefore not a Vitali set.  On the other hand, $\Bbb R/\big(\Bbb Z[\frac12]\big)$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R$, so it is not a Vitali set.

Comment: I know of Lebesgue.  But you talk about this other guy, Lebesque ... :)

Comment: I'm unaware of a convention that calls Lebesgue non-measurable sets "Vitali sets". As far as I know, only the ones that intersect each class of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$ in exactly one point are called Vitali sets.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm guessing the OP means a set of representatives of $\mathbb{R}/\left(\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)$ chosen in $[0,1]$ for example.

Comment: @GEdgar fixed, I believe.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512874/

Answer (score -2):

Every set of representatives of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ will contain a pair of elements differing by a rational not in $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ e.g. $\frac13$ and therefore it cannot be a Vitali set.

However by a theorem of Sierpinski every countable set with no isolated points is homeomorphic to all the others so (tentatively) the set is homeomorphic to a Vitali set.

Please comment / criticise as this is a very tentative answer.

Comment: a few downvotes but no guidance or better answers :(